# Why are variable types that appear the same not being recognized as the same?

Tags: c++, inheritance, template-specialization, type-traits, decltype-auto

I really don't know what to do with this. It seems code is behaving differently depending on where a variable (or its type) originates. And I don't know how to work around this to get consistent behavior.

Below (and linked) is a distilled version of some code being developed for [**fmtster**](https://github.com/HarmanFOSS/fmtster).

In this code, specialized structures are created for a specific types (`float` and `std::string` in the example). Some member functions in the templatized structures (not shown in the example) are then called by the framework ({fmt} or `std::format`).

`is_foobar_v<>` is designed to check whether, for the specified type, there is a specialization of the `foo` structure which has `bar` as its base class. When the specific type is used as the template argument, it works correctly. Also, when `decltype()` is used with the local variables, it also works correctly:

- `is_foobar_v<int>` returns `false`, because `foo<int>` *does not* use `bar` as a base class
- `is_foobar_v<float>` returns `true`, because `foo<float>` *does* use `bar` as a base class.
- `is_foobar_v<string>` returns `true`, because `foo<string>` *does* use `bar` as a base class.

(Clearly use of `decltype()` is not an issue.)

However, next in the code is one example from two places where `is_foobar_v<>` fails. The code below steps through the elements of a `tuple<>`, checking whether a `foo<>` structure, using that type as the template argument, is based on `bar`. `is_foobar_v<>` always returns `false`.

Note that I've also added an explicit instantiation of `foo<>` objects, to show which constructors are called. You'll note that these logs show that the code does not instantiate the proper specialization inside the lambda. Oddly, in the actual code, the instantiation actually works correctly, even though my check fails. However, I was not able to figure out why it fails to instantiate the correct specialization structure in this distilled code. After most of a day wasted trying, I'm hoping that is not related to the check failure.

I want to reiterate that this is one of two places where I have encountered this. The other was in a simpler templated member function calling a visitor function, and it was not related to the `tuple<>` loop and it did not use a lambda. In that case, I was able to work around the problem because the type in question was available explicitly as a template parameter (or more specifically as a type trait of a template parameter (i.e. `T::value_type`)).

That workaround is not available here.

Also, as I mentioned, in the actual code, the correct specialization is being created. So there, I also tried to check whether a function that only exists in the `bar` equivalent is present. I tried the code snippet below the test program, which also didn't work. And I tried to actually instantiate a `foo<>` object and then `dynamic_cast<>` its pointer to a `bar` pointer, which I would check for `nullptr`. But in that environment, I don't seem to be allowed to create the `foo<>` object explicitly.

Anyway, on to the code:

[Code on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/W3jqYerYr)

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::boolalpha;
#include <string>
using std::string;
#include <tuple>
using std::make_tuple;

// template argument iteration for std::tuple<>
template<typename F, typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
void ForEachElement(const std::tuple<Ts...>& tup,
                    F fn,
                    std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    (void)(int[]) { 0, ((void)fn(std::get<Is>(tup)), 0)... };
}
template<typename F, typename...Ts>
void ForEachElement(const std::tuple<Ts...>& tup, F fn)
{
    ForEachElement(tup, fn, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>());
}

template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    foo() { cout << "foo::foo<>()" << endl; }
};

struct bar
{
    bar() { cout << "bar::bar()" << endl; }
};

template<>
struct foo<float> : public bar
{
    foo() { cout << "foo::foo<float>()" << endl; }
};

template<>
struct foo<string> : public bar
{
    foo() { cout << "foo::foo<string>()" << endl; }
};


template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_foobar_v = std::is_base_of_v<bar, foo<T> >;

int main()
{
    int i;
    float f;
    string s;

    foo<int>();
    cout << "foo<" << typeid(int).name() << "> "
         << (is_foobar_v<int> ? "IS" : "is NOT")
         << " a child of bar" << endl;

    foo<float>();
    cout << "foo<" << typeid(float).name() << "> "
         << (is_foobar_v<float> ? "IS" : "is NOT")
         << " a child of bar" << endl;

    foo<string>();
    cout << "foo<" << typeid(string).name() << "> "
         << (is_foobar_v<string> ? "IS" : "is NOT")
         << " a child of bar" << endl;

    foo<decltype(i)>();
    cout << "foo<" << typeid(i).name() << "> "
         << (is_foobar_v<decltype(i)> ? "IS" : "is NOT")
         << " a child of bar" << endl;

    foo<decltype(f)>();
    cout << "foo<" << typeid(f).name() << "> "
         << (is_foobar_v<decltype(f)> ? "IS" : "is NOT")
         << " a child of bar" << endl;

    foo<decltype(s)>();
    cout << "foo<" << typeid(s).name() << "> "
         << (is_foobar_v<decltype(s)> ? "IS" : "is NOT")
         << " a child of bar" << endl;

    auto tup = make_tuple(i, f, s);
    ForEachElement(
        tup,
        [](const auto& elem)
        {
            foo<decltype(elem)>();
            cout << "foo<" << typeid(elem).name() << "> "
                 << (is_foobar_v<decltype((elem))> ? "IS" : "is NOT")
                 << " a child of bar" << endl;
        });
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
foo::foo<>()
foo<i> is NOT a child of bar
bar::bar()
foo::foo<float>()
foo<f> IS a child of bar
bar::bar()
foo::foo<string>()
foo<NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE> IS a child of bar
foo::foo<>()
foo<i> is NOT a child of bar
bar::bar()
foo::foo<float>()
foo<f> IS a child of bar
bar::bar()
foo::foo<string>()
foo<NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE> IS a child of bar
foo::foo<>()
foo<i> is NOT a child of bar
foo::foo<>()
foo<f> is NOT a child of bar
foo::foo<>()
foo<NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE> is NOT a child of bar
```

Another thing I tried:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool HasBarBaseHelper()
{ return false; }
template<>
constexpr bool HasBarBaseHelper<bar>()
{ return true; }

template<typename T>
constexpr bool HasBarBase()
{ return HasBarBaseHelper<fmt::formatter<T> >(); }

...

if (HasBarBaseHelper<foo<decltype(elem)> >())
{
...
```

I really don't understand why the check succeeds with `decltype()` of some variables, but not others. And as you can see by the output, the types appear to be exactly the same.

Any help appreciated.

Rick

Comment: Since `elem` is declared as `const auto& elem`, `decltype(elem)` is "reference to const `T`". And `foo<string const&>` does not derive from `bar`. Maybe use `is_foobar_v = std::is_base_of_v<bar, foo<std::remove_cv_t< std::remove_reference_t<T> > > >;` to remove the `const` and the `&` before applying `foo`.

Comment: I don't have time to go into your code, but I can give you some points: first, don't use `typeid().name` to check types. There is trick I use to check the real type. It's reliable and you can be sure it's exact: https://godbolt.org/z/PnbdM6Tv6 . Again, I didn't get over your code but an educated guess is telling me your issue is that some types from your expressions are references, which you will be able to see with my method.

Comment: Maybe I'm being dumb, or out-of-date, but what is `(void)(int[]) { 0, ((void)fn(std::get<Is>(tup)), 0)... };` ? Clang warns that it is a (C99-specific) compound literal and MSVC completely chokes on it.

Comment: Folks here are quick to call out use of VLAs (another g++ extension) in C++ code, so why not use *real* C++ here, too? `int a[] = { 0, ((void)fn(std::get<Is>(tup)), 0)... };` (followed by, if you want to silence warnings, `(void)(a);`) will do the same thing, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @AdrianMole That's a pre-c++17 pack expansion written as a compound literal, which is a compiler extension. Writing it as an initialization (with `[[maybe_unused]]`) has the same effect.

Comment: @RaymondChen, thank you. That is exactly what was causing my problem. I reluctantly admit to having missed those tools. Apparently `std::decay<>` didn't accomplish the same thing, as I thought it would. If you want to post an answer, i can checkmark it.

Comment: @bolov, thank you for your advice. When debugging I will try to use your suggestion. But I sometimes want to print more than one type for comparison, as in this example. More importantly, I am also trying to be better about printing types where appropriate for logging, such as when a type is not one of those that are handled correctly. (**fmtster** has some type limitations, for example with nested arguments, & I am trying to be more specific about the issue when possible.) Is there a way to get that more detailed information while completing a compilation?

Comment: @AdrianMole, thank you for pointing out this anachronism. I usually don't borrow from a SO answer unless I understand most of what's going on inside, but in this case, I admit to pilfering it without much understanding. I never really understood that particular line. However, your query made me double-check my research & revealed that the same functionality appears to be part of the standard that I missed the first time around. A simple `std::apply` (C++17) seems to have easily replaced the `ForEachElement` macro, once I worked out the syntax. Again, thanks for (nicely) challenging this code.